# Saving values in an array discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've started coding on Discord.js and I'm not a professional at it but I have made a discord bot and I won't save values in an array could someone help me do it?

My code is like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'foo') {
    message.channel.send('bar')}
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong')}
})
```

Instead of writing

```js
 if (message.content.toLowerCase() === ...
```

Over and over again, is there a better method to do it?
I heard you can use JSON files and arrays but I have no clue how it works.

Comment: I'd suggest you check out this: https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/ for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is second answer without any things, just plain and simple to your problem:-

add this line in new line after `client.on('message', message => {`  :-

```
let command = message.content.toLowerCase();
```

Now replace "message.content.toLowerCase()" in each if condition with "command".

It would look something like this:-

```
client.on('message', message => {

   let command = message.content.toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'foo') {
    message.channel.send('bar')}
  if (command === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong')}
})
}
```

*Although both of my solutions aren't related to array/json or anything like that, as you mentioned but both are simple solution to your answer. It wouldn't be wise to use array and json just for the same, as it can make code long and hard to understand.*

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your message content as `'foo sentence'` for example. Then according to your if statement (`if(message.content.toLowerCase()==='foo')`), it will not execute. Because your message content is compared to 'foo' which is not the same. 'foo sentence' and not 'foo'. If you just want to compare the first part of the message content you should split you message content by 'space'.

```
let args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(/ +/);
```

args is an array of string which is split by space. So in this example, args will be `["foo","sentence"]`. With the help of this, you can now just compare the message.

```
if(args[0]==='foo'){
//do your thing
}
```

This checks if the first part of message content is equal to 'foo'.

For more info, see [how to create commands with user inputs](http://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to do something like this

```js
const Prefix = "$";
Client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith(Prefix)){
        let args = message.content.slice(1).split(" ");
        let CommandHandler = new Commands(Client, message, args);
        let execute = CommandHandler[args[0]];
        if(execute){
            execute();
        }
    }
});
class Commands {
    constructor(client, message, args){
        this.Client = client;
        this.Message = message;
        this.Args = args;
    }
    ping(){
        Message.channel.send("Pong")
    }
    sus(){
        Message.channel.send("AMONGUS");
    }
}
```

Now put any commands as functions inside the `Commands` class (in lower case) and it'll go automatically. (Now you don't have to do if..else if..else if.......else anymore)

I know you wanted help about using arrays but Using classes and objects are more useful.
Learn about  classes from here:

- [From w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)
- [From Mozilla Developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0):

This is more simpler to understand, as you have just started.

replace your code with:-

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    // Check for command

    if (message.content.startsWith("yourprefix")) {
        //replace yourprefix with prefix of bot

        let args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).split(' ');
        let command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        switch (command) {
      case 'ping':
      case 'alias':

        message.channel.send("ping");

       break;
      case 'foo':
      case 'alias':

        message.channel.send("bar");

      break;
    }
}
```

Benefit of this code:-

**You can add multiple alias of each command by writing case each time.**

**This way it will be easier for you to manage codes**

**It'll solve your main problem of writing .toLowerCase each time**

NOTE:- *If at starting is to check your prefix, if you don't want to check for prefix remove that!*